# Download Selected File from Directory with PHP

Tags: php, file, forms, download

I have a script written (below) which properly displays the contents of a specific directory and creates a radio button for each file.  I would like to be able to select a file and download that file to my computer.

Is this possible by changing the "action" of the form?  Or is there another script or a change I need to make to my script to accomplish this?

```
    <form name="myform" action="#" method="POST">



<?php
$dirPath = dir('./images');
$imgArray = array();
while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
{
  if ((substr($file, -3)=="gif") || (substr($file, -3)=="jpg") || (substr($file, -3)=="png"))
  {
     $imgArray[ ] = trim($file);
  }
}
$dirPath->close();
sort($imgArray);
$c = count($imgArray);
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
{
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"group1\" value=\"" . $imgArray[$i] . "\">" . $imgArray[$i] . "<br />";
}
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="download">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put this at the beginning of your existing script:

```
if(isset($_POST['group1'])){
    $f=preg_replace('/(\.\.\/?)+/','',$_POST['group1']);
    if(file_exists('./images/'.$f)){
        header("Content-type: ".filetype('./images/'.$f));
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$f.'"');
        echo file_get_contents('./images/'.$f);
        exit;
    }
}
```

It's my preferred way of doing what Cyclone was pointing at.

Comment: Thanks - this works and it shows the proper file is downloaded but the file is always empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Tony Sorry I forgot to echo the contents! haha, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

`header('Location: YOURFILEDOWNLOADURL; Content-type: application/force-download');`

should work, haven't tested.

Comment: Sorry, bit of a noob, not sure how to make this work. @cyclone

Comment: @Tony just change `YOURFILEDOWNLOADURL` out for the url of the file being downloaded

Comment: this gives me a 403 Forbidden error message when I place this line in my code.  When I leave it out of my code the script works fine, except that the image files are opened by the browser rather than a prompt for a dialogue box.  It gives me the error message when the original page loads...so it doesn't even give me a chance to select the file I would like to download.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a download button for every file in the directory? There seems no need to use a form for this.

Remove all form HTML and change your 'for'-loop to this and you should be fine:

```
foreach($imgArray as $filename)
{
    echo "<a href=\"./images/$filename\">Download '$filename'</a>";
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

(since this uses foreach you can also drop the line that sets $c to count($imgArray) ).

If you insist on using a form, I suggest you either:

- send the form to a parse script that reads out which file was selected, and then forwards the user to that file like how Cyclone suggests, or,
- use JavaScript to directly forward the page to the selected image when the Submit-button is pressed.

Both solutions are needlessly complicated for what you are trying to accomplish, however.

Comment: Thanks @Will0.  Is there a way to force a download dialogue box rather than having the browser try to open the file itself?